# Translate regex for Java

Tags: java, regex

How can this regex `^\d+(?:[\.\,]\d+)?$` to be usable with Java.

```
input.matches("^\\d+(?:[\\.\\,]\\d+)?$"); // Redundant character escape
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace or explain the unwanted behavior.

Comment: characters inside the class don't need to be escaped at all: `[.,]`

Comment: You probably don't need the backslashes in the character class. Try just `[.,]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is fine. Note: Using `matches`; implicitly adds `^` at the start and `$` at the end of your pattern. Also, you do not need to escape the characters inside of your character class.

```
input.matches("\\d+(?:[,.]\\d+)?");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code executes fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "123";
    System.out.println(input.matches("^\\d+(?:[\\.\\,]\\d+)?$"));
    input = "123.123";
    System.out.println(input.matches("^\\d+(?:[\\.\\,]\\d+)?$"));
    input = "123,123";
    System.out.println(input.matches("^\\d+(?:[\\.\\,]\\d+)?$"));
    input = "123..123";
    System.out.println(input.matches("^\\d+(?:[\\.\\,]\\d+)?$"));
}
```

prints

```
true
true
true
false
```

As per [regex101](http://regex101.com/), your matched string will start with one ore more digits, followed by a non capturing group that occurs once or not at all, containing a `.` or a `,`, literally, and one or more digits, and then end.

That's what you have, that's what will match.